# how to improve mysql query speedy with indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I must run this query with MySQL:

```
select requests.id, requests.id_temp, categories.id
from opadithree.requests inner join
     opadi.request_detail_2
     on substring(requests.id_sub_temp, 3) = request_detail_2.id inner join 
     opadithree.categories
     on request_detail_2.theme = categories.cu_code
where categories.atc = false and id_sub_temp like "2_%";
```

However for some reason the query is too slow. The table `requests` has 15583 rows. The table `request_detail_2` 66469 rows and the table `categories` has 13452 rows.

The most problematic column `id_sub_temp` has data strings in the following formats: "2_number" or "3_number".

Do you know some trick to make the query faster?

Comment: Well, joining with substring for sure is slowing your query. May creating an index with the problematic rows can help you.

Comment: Fix the poor table design and the problem is gone. (When you don't need that substring.)

Comment: I don't have the permission to change the design of the table unfortunately.

Comment: While I agree that the table design is poor, I don't think fixing it would matter much.  Bill's indexes seem optimal in spite of the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the indexes I'd try:

First, I need an index so your WHERE condition on `id_sub_temp` can find the rows needed efficiently. Then add the column `id_temp` so the result can select that column from the index instead of forcing it to read the row.

```
CREATE INDEX bk1 ON requests (id_sub_temp, id_temp);
```

Next I'd like the join to categories to filter by `atc=false` and then match the `cu_code`. I tried reversing the order of these columns so `cu_code` was first, but that resulted in an expensive index-scan instead of a lookup. Maybe that was only because I was testing with empty tables. Anyway, I don't think the column order is important in this case.

```
CREATE INDEX bk2 ON categories (atc, cu_code);
```

The join to request_detail_2 is currently by primary key, which is already pretty efficient.